# Exclude dash (-) from word separators in vi

Tags: unix, vi, ctags

vi uses dash and space as word separators. is there any way to exclude dash from word separators ?

This is required to work with the symbols generated by ctags exe. when symbol contain a "-" ,vi tags fails to locate that even though symbol is generated properly.

For example Symbol - EX01-VAR-LOCAL when using the ctrl+] to search tag for this, vi looks only for EX01 not the complete symbol EX01-VAR-LOCAL

although if used with vi -t EX01-VAR-LOCAL or in command mode :tag EX01-VAR-LOCAL works fine.

i am looking for the solution for vi editor only not vim

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a true `vi`, only `elvis`, `nvi`, and `vim`. In `vim` `:set lisp` will treat - as part of a word, rather than as a separator for both tags and motion.  `elvis` does not (documentation claims it's unimplemented and does nothing), and `nvi` responds that `:set lisp` is unimplemented.

Update: a lightly updated `vi`, http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/ does indeed handle "-" as part of words for tag purposes (but not motion) when `:set lisp` is active.

Comment: Not sure if "only ... vim" is the right term! (-:

Answer (score 1):

See the help for `'iskeyword'` in `vim`.

```
:help 'iskeyword'
```

Comment: Thank you @musiphil.  That was a very helpful pointer and helped me to fix a similar issue with a different filetype.